# execute result block as shell commands

Tags: org-mode

I would like to build a shell command using elisp and then printing the result so it is stored in a `#+RESULTS` block and from there execute that result block as a shell command still inside the org-mode document.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe you will find this helpful http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2019/02/12/Using-results-from-one-code-block-in-another-org-mode/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe the header argument [`:wrap`](http://orgmode.org/manual/wrap.html) can help, e.g.,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :wrap src sh
(format "echo %s" (shell-quote-argument user-full-name))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_src sh
echo Xu\ Chunyang
#+END_src

#+RESULTS:
: Xu Chunyang
```

Comment: I often use the `:wrap "src json"` option for a org mode source block, when the output is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example org-file below. The `emacs-lisp` source block on top prints the shell source block inclusive the limiters `#+begin_src sh` and `#+end_src`.

The result format of the `emacs-lisp` source block is `raw`. That way the generated shell source block is directly embedded into the org file.

If you evaluate the org buffer with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-babel-execute-buffer` the Elisp source block and the updated shell source block are executed.

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results raw
(princ "#+begin_src sh
echo \"Hello World.\";\n#+end_src")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_src sh
echo "Hello World.";
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello World.
```